# Asp.net WebForms Error with Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, webforms, anonymous

Please help me! I am experiencing an odd problem with anonymous types in Asp.net/WebForms using Visual Studio 2008.
In the page markup, this generates a "Type Expected" error (just an example):

```
<%=new { property = "somevalue" }.ToString() %>
```

Or even

```
<%var x = new { property = "somevalue" }; 
Response.Write(x.ToString()); %>
```

If I put this in a method, this works fine:

```
<%=ShowIt() %>
```

...in codebehind...

```
public string ShowIt() 
{ return new { property = "somevalue" }.ToString(); }
```

What can I do to get Web Forms to recognize anonymous type/syntax?
I tried Google.

PLEASE NOTE: I am aware that the above code is not good practice. I can't seem to use anonymous types AT ALL in markup in this project. IE: even passing as an argument:

```
<%=ShowIt(new { prop1 = "a", prop2 = 2 }) %>
```

Does not seem to work.

Comment: You've answered your own question - put it in a method?

Comment: Thanks -- but while my simple example does not make sense in practice -- I actually am trying to pass an anonymous type object to a method as a parameter (sort of like how MVC's HTML helpers work). For this scenario and its particular demands, that is not a good answer, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem in the web.config. Apparently it was missing a reference to the C# compiler under the "compilers" tag which is under the "system.codedom" tag.

```
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the following:

```
<%= new { property = "somevalue" }.ToString() %>
```

outputs the structure of the anonymous type:

```
{ property = somevalue }
```

Are you attempting to output the value of "property"?

If so use the following:

```
<%= new { property = "somevalue" }.property.ToString() %>
```

Either way, as Smudge202 states above, you should really use a code behind method as you can make your mark-up self documenting with a good method name.

Comment: My above code is just an example. I'm actually passing an anonymous type object to a function, sort of like how MVC's HTML helpers work. Perhaps there is something wrong with the project's web.config or something if this normally works with WebForms/2008/ASP.net markup.